# Printing total using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to get the total of 1,2,3,4 which I am able to achieve through code 1 but not code 2. Could someone please point out why is code 2 returning 4 and not 10?

CODE 1:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1,5):
    total = total + i

print(total)
10
```

CODE 2:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1,5):
    newtotal = total + i

print(newtotal)
4
```

Comment: What do you think is the value of total in the last iteration of Code 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is because in code2 total is not updating ,it always is zero because you initialised it to 0 so every time in for loop i gets updated like

```
newtotal = 0+1 = 1
next time
newtotal = 0+2 = 2
nex time
newtotal = 0+3 = 3
nex time
newtotal = 0+4 = 4
```

But in code 1 you are updating the value of total everytime with the statement

> total = total + i

```
first time
total = 0+1 = 1
//now total is 1
next time
total = 1+2 = 3
next time
total = 3+3 = 6
next time
total = 6+4 = 10
```

Hence the answer 10

Answer (score 0):

Because in CODE 2, in each iteration total is 0.

```
total = 0
newtotal = 0
for i in range(1,5):
    total = newtotal
    newtotal = total + i

print(newtotal)
```

Now here we are updating the value of total